# Error during starting Jboss 4.3 while binding default hsql datasource

Tags: jboss, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I get below error during JBoss start up.

```
[ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=Hypersonic,database=localDB
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties;
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.getConnection(HypersonicDatabase.java:768)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.startStandaloneDatabase(HypersonicDatabase.java:618)
    at org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase.startService(HypersonicDatabase.java:564)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
```

Background: I have added a new MS Access DB data source. For that, i am using ucanaccess library. Now, to bundle my code, i have created an executable uber jar which contains my main test program along with dependencies. Dependencies include following jars:

```
ucanaccess-4.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
hsqldb-2.3.1.jar
jackcess-2.1.6.jar
```

Further, I have configured my data source in MSAccess-ds.xml and deployed in deploy folder. And i have kept my uber jar named "Service-MSAccessDB.jar" inside server lib folder as well as Ear/lib. Now, on server startup i get above error.

Now, if i rename my jar to "EService-MSAccessDB.jar", The error goes away.

The issue I feel is that JBoss server lib already contains hsqldb.jar. And when i place my uber jar, it causes some conflict. On startup, it tries to find a method i.e. DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties; which is present in my uber jar but not in hsqldb.jar. And when i rename my uber jar such that it is alphabetically higher in order with respect to hsqldb.jar, issue goes away.

Now, my question is, why is it looking for such a method while configuring DefaultDS which is default configuration of JBoss. How to resolve this issue without renaming my Uber jar as appending "E" in front of my Jar name does not make sense.

Comment: As a side note JBoss EAP 4.3 hasn't been updated for 7 years now, you might want to update to a newer version of EAP (or Wildfly if you don't have support anymore) to fix the kilometer-long list of security flaws your server must have...

Comment: @Aaron I dont have an option to upgrade the jboss. I have a big team and all of them have this server setup along with application. Anyways, this is not a production server. It is used for training purpose only. And my code is also meant to work on all training servers. Thanks.

Comment: Alright so probably (hopefully?) no security concern. I still feel like a license-free Wildfly 10 would be closer to your prod servers (assuming an EAP 6.2+) than this EAP 4.3 and therefore be a better training tool. With this version you're missing a lot of modern features, be it JavaEE7 or exploitations tools such as the web console or CLI tool. Of course only you know the feasability of updating. Be assured that this isn't a critic of your question, I'm not answering it merely because I don't have the required knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the concern. Our production servers are on WAS 8. And i really do not have any authority to make that decision to change server. This jboss version is merely used for training and demo purpose to showcase the application to clients. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This JBoss server contains a copy of hsqldb.jar version 1.8.0.x for its internal use. You can replace it with a copy of hsqldb-2.3.1.jar (renamed to the name of the original jar) to avoid the conflict.

Comment: Won't that lead to internal usage problem? As i can see, there is lot of difference in both jar versions. Also, any idea on why is it referring to the function of my jar instead of the existing one? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: HSQLDB version 2.3.0 was tested successfully with JBoss 3.2.7. AFAIK there wasn't a major change in the next versions. The usage is for JBoss MQ which shouldn't occur in a test server. You may need to delete the localDB.xxx files in the JBoss data directory.